# Java: some error about the matrix with locate the smallest location

Tags: java

Here is what I have done

```
    java.util.Scanner input = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Rnter the number if rows and columns of the array: ");
    int row = input.nextInt();
    int col = input.nextInt();
    
    double numList[][] = new double[row][col];
    
    System.out.println("Enter the array:");
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
            numList[i][j] = input.nextDouble();
        }
    }
    int[] location;
    location = locateSmallest(numList);
    System.out.println("The location of the smallest element is at " + Arrays.toString(location));
}
    public static int[] locateSmallest(double[][] a){
    int i, j;
    double minNum = a[0][0];
    int minNumLocate[] = new int[2];
    for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++){       
        for (i =0; i < a[j].length; i++){
            if (a[j][i] < minNum){
                minNumLocate[j] = j;
                minNumLocate[i] = i;
             }
        }
    }
    return minNumLocate;   
}
```

}

overall it should be done for int input, like here

```
   Enter the number if rows and columns of the array: 3 4
   Enter the array:
   1 2 3 4
   3 4 5 6
   3 4 5 6
   The location of the smallest element is at [0, 0]
```

but I enter the double input, it comes up error, like here

```
Enter the number if rows and columns of the array: 3 4
Enter the array:
1.5 3 2 10
3.5 4 2 1
35 44 5.5 9.6
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 2
```

I don't know where should I correct it, Please help me to check it,
if it is possible please help me to check that where can I improve more clear in the same time
THANK YOU GUYS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a[j].length` will be 3 and `int minNumLocate[]` is dim equal 2. So there is nothing to protect of j or i been lower than 2.

Just change how you defined the index on minNumLocate assignment :

```
    int minNumLocate[] = new int[2];
    for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++){       
        for (i =0; i < a[j].length; i++){
            if (a[j][i] < minNum){
                minNumLocate[1] = j;
                minNumLocate[0] = i;
             }
        }
    }
```

Also, there is missing the update of `minNum` with the minimum found.

```
    int minNumLocate[] = new int[2];
    for (j = 0; j < a.length; j++){       
        for (i =0; i < a[j].length; i++){
            if (a[j][i] < minNum){
                minNumLocate[1] = j;
                minNumLocate[0] = i;
                minNUm = a[j][i];
             }
        }
    }
```

Last optimization, will be use the `col` and `row` values from the input

```
     int minNumLocate[] = new int[2];
     minNUm = a[0][0];
     for (j = 0; j < row ; j++){       
        for (i =0; i < col; i++){
            if (a[j][i] < minNum){
                minNumLocate[1] = j;
                minNumLocate[0] = i;
                minNUm = a[j][i];
             }
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, the error is solved, but it still has a little problem with the output, after my checking, it should have happened at the same part that what you have advised for me. I find tried serval input and it has the correct location so as the value, but I input this also is the 3 x 4 matrix `code`23.5 35 2 10   4.5 3 45 3.5   35 44 5.5 9.6`code`, the minvalue should 2, it correct, and the location should be [0,3], but the output is [2,3],

Comment: is there any possible problem in other parts?

Comment: Well, add a print inside of the nested loop to see the indexes and the values comparison. I updated the post, try to reuse the row and col input variables instaed of recalculating the size.

Comment: thank a lot, finally, I have achieved my target.

Comment: You'r welcome. Can you accept my answer for future search? @DickyChiang